# How do I find Troll Salve?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm playing through the earliest content of a Sylvari ranger and there's this quest from Mender Aviala.  It feels like it's a no-brainer; a go-do-this-simple-thing quest but I'm lost and my local peers aren't being helpful.  I go to the what was the SE of the map at the time I got the quest and there's this circle of jungle trolls and there are a couple of events (rescuing puppies and killing the troll king) and I've done those each several times while wandering around just killing trolls.  The one person in-game who answered my questions said the salve is just lying around but I haven't seen any such thing.

So, am I in the right place?  Is it a drop or some terrain feature or what?  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enter the instance for the troll salve.  Look for the green icon that looks like a hurricane, and tell it yes you want to continue your story.  Once in your instance the troll salve will appear.  The trolls attack in groups in the instance so it is a bit harder than the trolls in the regular world map.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this quest yet, but you can see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhBXYfUawgg) showing how the quest is done. At about minute 3:10 you can see where the troll salve is found.

Hope it helps

Comment: That's fascinating!  I've been in that spot many, many times and there's never been a troll sap.

Comment: I would try restarting the mission, and making sure the quest objective is correct when you are suposed to find this item. If it still fails, I would suggest reporting it as a bug from the support option.

Comment: @clweeks Make sure you're actually in the instance!